# Chrome chokes on TOO many XHR2 requests

Tags: html, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, blob

I have a "JSFiddle-like" demo of fetching PNG (Binary Blobs) in a tight loop using XHR2. This first demo grabs 341 PNG images, and then saves them in IndexedDB (using PouchDB).

This demo works fine: http://codepen.io/DrYSG/pen/hpqoD

*(To operate, first press [Delete DB], Reload Page, wait for Status = Ready (you should see that it plans to fetch 341 tiles), then press [Download tiles]. )*

The next demo is the same code (identical JS, CSS, HTML), but it tries to get 6163 PNG files (again from Google Drive). This time you will see many XHR 0 errors in the console log.

http://codepen.io/DrYSG/pen/qCGxi

The Algorithm it uses is as follows:

- Test for presence of XHR2, IndexedDB, and Chrome (which does not have binary blobs, but Base64). and show this status info
- Fetch a JSON manifest of PNG tiles from GoogleDrive (I have 171 PNG tiles, each 256x256 in size). The manifest lists their names and sizes.
- Store the JSON manifest in the DB
- MVVM and UI controls are from KendoUI (This time I did not use their superb grid control, since I wanted to explore CSS3 Grid Styling).
- I am using the nightly build of PouchDB
- All files PNG file are feteched from Google Drive (NASA Blue Marble.
- I created the tile pyramid with [Safe FME 2013 Desktop](http://www.safe.com/fme/fme-technology/fme-desktop/overview).

My guess is what is happening is that all these XHR2 requests are being fired async, being placed on a thread separate from the JavaScript thread, and then when there are too many pending requests, Chrome is getting sick.

FireFox does not have this issue, nor does IE10.

You can fork the code, and try different values for line 10: (max number of tiles to fetch).

I have submitted a bug to **[Chromium Bugs](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=244910&thanks=244910&ts=1369845799)**, but does anyone have any experience in throttling the async XHR2 fetches for large downloads of data to the Chrome Browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chromium folks acknowledge this is something that they should fix: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=244910, but in the meantime I have implemented throttling using jquery defer/resolve to keep the number of threads low.

Update: I am going to delete my codepen, since I don't need to show this error anymore.