# Completion of async download (jQuery custom event? Deferred?)

Tags: html, jquery, multithreading, jquery-events

I am using Chrome to download a large PNG files (map tiles 256x256). [Chrome chokes on TOO many XHR2 requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819676/chrome-chokes-on-too-many-xhr2-requests)

If I simply loop through and do 5K of these, then the Chrome Browser does not throttle and it runs out of memory (The Chromium Folks are going to fix this some day: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=244910 )

Till then I need to do my own throttling.

What I think I am looking for is to start of a "thread" that will do about a batch of about 100 xhr2 fetches and IndexedDB (IDB) stores. Then when it is done "signal" the parent process to feed it 100 more, and loop till done (that is how I would do it it C++, C#, VB.NET etc).

But this is in JavaScript, which I am just getting back into after many years away from it.

What should I be looking for? JQuery Deferred?  Promise? A Custom Event? [`trigger()` & `bind()`] or some other way of doing this thread coordination (monitors, semaphores) etc. The browser does put XHR2 and IDB requests on separate threads, but does not give typical IPC control mechanisms.

Some pointers to prior work and some tips is all I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first considered creating a limited number of web workers. But IndexedDB in web workers is not working well yet in FireFox and IE10. (either sync IDB or async IDB). I think async IDB works in Chrome.

So I chose instead to use Jquery Defer, and wait for the IDB put to finish and then signal with $.resolve() to start a new fetch/save thread.

Works fine.